# How to grant access to 'All-Projects' project for only Administrator in Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I have setup a Gerrit server in an Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).
Gerrit version: 2.14.6

Now the question is, for some reason I would like to configure Gerrit that only Administrator users will able to view/clone/modify 'All-Projects' and 'All-Users' projects. No other users like 'Registered Users' will not able to access.

All other projects will be visible to all users like registered users or specified groups.

Is there any way to perform this operation?

**Note:**
If this question is redundant, please forward the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant:

```
refs/* Read ALLOW
```

only to Administrators in All-Projects project, but you'll need, of course, grant the required read permission to the other users/groups to all repositories. To facilitate the setup you can have an inherit struture (using the "Rights Inherit From" feature) like the following:

```
All-Projects
    Public-Projects
        xxxx
        yyyy
    Private-Projects
        wwwww
        zzzzz
```